# Sort Mongo subArray

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

```
[
   {

    "t": "Sample Question",
    "d": "2018-12-23T21:21:03.430Z",
    "aa": [
        {

            "q": 1,
            "n": "5bee73accda38",
            "iU": "5bee73accda38/5c1f3d7341977/1.mp4"
        },
        {

            "q": 4,
            "n": "5bee73accda38",
            "iU": "5bee73accda38/5c1f3d7341977/1.mp4"
        }
    ]
}]
```

I'm new to Mongo and trying to sort SubArray(Descending) in MongoDB but still unable to achieve sort based on "q" (Descending Order) index in sub-array.

This is what I have tried but got no success

```
Question.find({}, function(err, question) {

if (err)
  res.send(err); 

}).sort({'d':-1,'aa.q':-1 }).skip(page).limit(10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use `$aggregate` and inside `$unwind`, `$sort` and then `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$aa" },
  { $sort: { "aa.q": -1 }},
  { $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "t": { $first: "$t" },
      "d": { $first: "$d" },
      "aa": { $push: "$aa" }
    }
  }
])
```

See it [working here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/BdbzFCfPtO3)